# Is it necessary for AWS Lambda to have charged NAT gateway to access external resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mqtt, nat

I'm trying to create an AWS Lambda function that is to be invoked by an Amazon Echo Skill. The Lambda function should connect to an MQTT broker, which is not in the AWS, and I noticed that the Lambda function alone was not able to access to the external resource. I have tried several configurations and it could connect to the broker after creating an NAT gateway. However, the NAT gateway is a charged service and I wonder if it is necessary.

Here is my question. Is it necessary to have the charged NAT gateway in my situation for the Lambda function to access to the external resource? If not, what else should I do? I would welcome any idea that would let an Echo Skill publish an MQTT message to my MQTT broker, even without the AWS Lambda.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need an NAT Gateway only of you are running the Lambda function in a VPC. By default, a Lambda function is not run in a VPC and will have access to the internet and external resources.

Check if the lambda function you are running is running in a VPC.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the Lambda function within a VPC and want to access the outside world then yes, a NAT gateway is essential. However, you don't actually need to use Amazon's paid NAT gateway service.

You can instead throw up an EC2 Instance using a public NAT Gateway AMI ([guide here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html)). I had a simple Lambda function requiring access to both the internet and a database within my VPC. Paying for a dedicated NAT Gateway just seemed like overkill, so I used this image and it works a charm, even on a `t2.nano` instance! Obviously a much cheaper option.